# How to use model classes in both Website and Web service?

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, rest, model

I am building a demo application using Spring Web MVC , Hibernate  and Jersey for REST services.For this I created two dynamic web projects - one for the site, one for the service. All the model classes are defined in the website project ,  as they are the ones passed to the views.

Now, all my Hibernate code is in the web service ,  and it also requires these same model classes. Currently , I have created the exact same model classes in the web service project also  ( duplicate code ).  Is this correct ?

The data exchange is through JSON (using the GSON library),  so each time there is a request /response,   i am recreating the objects from this JSON.

Is this how it should be done .  Everything works perfectly , but I was wondering if there is a way I could use the same classes in the model / web service in it ?

Should I use a third project that contains only the model classes and reference the same one in both projects?  Will that be sufficient ?

Comment: A third project with the shared classes is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Why not having one project only with a backend and a frontend modules.

The backend contains services, repositories, transaction manager and data sources.

The fronted can have both the web app and the web services in a single war. You can use two different root paths for MVC and WS:

1. web-context/web-app/
2. web-context/rest/

Comment: Hi Vlad,  this is only a demo , but in my actual app , the rest service will be on a different server. So I was simulating that using two projects.  But sure, your answer would also be perfect if I was hosting on the same server. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, you can have 2 web modules to fulfill your demo requirements.